# Is it possible to retrieve data from a customDialog?

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

Is it possible to open a custom dialog component and then send back data to the component that opened the custom dialog?

```
this._dialogService.showCustomDialog({
  component: CustomSelectComponent,
  providers: [{provide: 'ROOM_ID', useValue: 1}],
  isModal: true,
  styles: {'width': '580px'},
  clickOutsideToClose: true
}).subscribe((dialogReference: MdlDialogReference) => {
    dialogReference.onHide().subscribe((data) => {

      // DATA SHOULD CONTAIN THE DATA PASSED IN TO THE hide METHOD
      console.log(data); 

    });
});
```

Comment: there is a test https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/blob/master/src/lib/components/dialog/mdl-dialog.service.spec.ts#L146 that shows how to pass data...

Comment: @michael thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. Although the TS compiler has some trouble compiling it because the onHide method has a void as datatype on its notify subscribers method

Comment: right. seems this should be any... -> https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/issues/403